# How to permanently move application to /system partition?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-j5

I'm running Android 6.0.1 on Galaxy J5 (SM-J500FN) and the main issue is disk space. If a system app is updated, old .apk remains on `/system` partition and the updated one is installed into `/data` partition.

You may permanently remove useless system apps and free up space on `/system` partition, then convert user-installed apps into system apps using Link2SD. But after reboot all settings are lost because these apps are reinstalled again.

When you update these apps again, old versions stay in `/system` and new are installed into `/data`. You cannot change this behavior, can you?

I found another trick:

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
mkdir /system/xapk
mv /data/app/pl.blinkee.mobile-1 /system/xapk
ln -s /system/xapk/pl.blinkee.mobile-1 /system/app/pl.blinkee.mobile-1
```

You cannot make hard link between different partitions but you can make symbolic link. However, after app update, this link will be overridden and updated .apk will be installed into `/data` again.

Workaround is to set up cron job that moves these apps into `/system` and makes symbolic links in `/data`.

The best idea seems to repartition drive, shrink `/system`, extend `/data`. Any safe way to do it?

BTW: What suffix `-1` or `-2` means at the end of folder name?